# Launch view controller after remote notification is clicked?

Tags: ios, notifications

I want to open a viewcontroller that is a rooted in a tabbarviewcontroller after a remote notification is clicked..how is this possible?

i am on a phone so I can't highlight code separately but here it is

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


If(launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]){
//what do I put here?

}
```

Comment: How is that viewcontroller initialized? when? where?

Comment: its initialized when the user clicks on the corresponding tab bar item of that view controller

Answer (score 0):

try this (i assumed that your method is in your `AppDelegate` class)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


      If(launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey])
      {

        UITabBarController * tabController  = (UITabBarController*)_window.rootViewController;
        YourViewController * yvc = (YourViewController*)[tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:yvc animated:YES completion:nil];
      }
}
```

(or)
EDIT: this may work

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
MainViewController *mvc = (MainViewController *)appDelegate.window.rootViewController;    
YourViewController *yvc = (YourViewController*)[mvc.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewStoryBoardID"];
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:yvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: can I call the tabBarController through storyboardId instead? I don't think my tabBarController is the root view controller. I have a navigation view controller which leads to a splash screen which then either leads to a sign in screen (which leads to the tab bar controller after sign in) or goes to the tab bar controller directly if the user is already signed in